# What is the pros / cons of compiling TypeScript into single js file?

Tags: typescript

As title asked. Whats the pros and cons of translating multiple .ts files into a single .js file?
e.g. Is it just performance reason? Will it make debugging harder?

Comment: Yes it will make debugging harder. Merging multiple files is mainly recommended for production deployment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends entirely on you project setup and environment.

If you are taking advantage of http/2 and its ability to send multiple files over one channel, whether you concatenate the files or not will not affect page-load performance. If you don't, performance will be improved by loading one large file instead of multiple smaller files.

If you are thinking about concatenating files, you are not using dependency loaders. This is ok, but this means that you need to reference all your files in the html page. This is simple if you only have one concatenated file to reference, and a bit harder if you have hundreds of files. You could use a build tool like gulp to build your html and include all references automatically, but if you don't, you will have a royal mess.

Regarding debugging, you can use sourcemaps which mean that you can debug your typescript directly in the browser, and that is a really good idea. Just like you can debug C# instead of of the compiled IL. If you are using sourcemaps, your debugging experience will be the same regardless of whether you are concatenating files or not. Use sourcemaps when developing with TypeScript.

Comment: I mark this as answer instead of Chiru's one because its not saying making a single js file is absolute evil. At least I can think of a little advantage such as faster compile time when using lite server watch mode. I can obfuscate my code together with single js file output to make my app esp game applications) harder to hack.

Answer (score 1):

Transpiling your sources into one single file…

- …makes debugging harder (yes, there's sourcemaps, but then you'll have to take care of not including them in your production build, leading to a bigger build pipeline). Though, If you use [good transpilers](http://babeljs.io/), you'll probably already use sourcemaps anyway.
- …leads to bad website/initial rendering performance (especially with HTTP/2, big bundles are now a thing of the past. Just use HTTP/2 and something like jspm).
- …prevents you from using hot-reloading plugins in an acceptable manner (that is, plugins that automatically refresh your browser once a file changes). If you change only one source file, only that file should compile; it's unnecessary to re-build the whole bundle. Big applications become pretty unmaintainable if you bundle everything up on file changes.
- …doesn't affect how much you need to put into your HTML files. Hence, what @Alex says is not entirely true. Your HTML should only import one core module anyway; it doesn't matter if you bundle everything up or not. Have a look at `System.import`, the [WHATWG Loader spec](https://whatwg.github.io/loader/) and [jspm](http://jspm.io/). Also have a look at the [Akamai HTTP/2 demo](https://http2.akamai.com/demo).

TL;DR: **Do not create a single bundle.** It's a thing of the past and will likely die with web servers (and browsers) optimizing for HTTP/2.

Comment: "Just use HTTP/2" - we have 2016, not 2020. The big server distributions (Debian, RHEL) don't even ship web servers that support HTTP 2. And browsers, well...

Comment: @jgillich HTTP/2 is on nginx-mainline already; nginx already provides [mainline packages](http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/) specifically for Debian and [RHEL](http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/rhel/). There's also a bunch of HTTP/2-compliant C++ and node servers.  Big companies such as Google, Cloudflare or Facebook serve their production code with HTTP/2 already (check with curl).  All major browsers already ship with [HTTP/2](http://caniuse.com/#feat=http2) and it's enabled by default (some force TLS, which isn't a bad thing per se). So why wait another *four* years?

Comment: 1: You should always use sourcemaps when using typescript, hence debugging will never be harder just because you concat files. 2/3/4. If one is thinking about concatenating files, one is not using asynchronous dependency loading anyway, which is ok. But then you have to include them all in your html unless you concat them. And if one is not loading dependencies with a dependency loader, loading many smaller files instead of one big will be worse for page-load if not using http/2, which still is not the de facto standard.